# Converting deprecated elasticsearch query to 7.12

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm in the process of upgrading my elastic search instance to the current version (7.12) as of this writing. Can someone help me convert our current request body to one that will work?

```
{"query"=>
  {"filtered"=>
    {"filter"=>
      {"and"=>
        [{"term"=>{"foo"=>"true"}},
         {"or"=>
           [{"terms"=>
              {"ids"=>
                ["32",
                 "644",
                ]}},
            {"missing"=>{"field"=>"ids"}}]}]}}},
 "facets"=>{}}
```

All the nested hash is really messing with my head :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [`filtered`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/query-dsl-filtered-query.html) query is replaced by [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.12/query-dsl-bool-query.html)
2. `must` is the same as logical AND operator and `should` is the same as logical OR operator
3. `missing` query is replaced by `must_not` along with [exists query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html)
4. [`facets`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-facets.html) have been replaced by [aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-aggregations.html)

The modified query will be

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "foo": "true"
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "terms": {
                  "ids": [
                    "32",
                    "644"
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must_not": {
                    "exists": {
                      "field": "ids"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {}
}
```